Saving tiff stack with a colormap with tifffile library
Has anyone ever tried to save a tiff with a colormap? Since the documentation for tifffile library is not very detailed, I can't seem to find a solution. For example, I have 5 tiff stacks and I want to save each one of them with a different color channel.
My code to save one stack with red channel:
tifffile.imwrite(
                Path(tif_output_store, name + ".tif"),
                np.moveaxis(tf, -1, 0).astype(np.uint16),
                imagej=True, compression ='zlib',
                metadata=ijmetadata,
                colormap=np.vstack([255, 0, 0]).astype('uint16') * 256
            )

Unfortunately this is throwing me ValueError: invalid colormap shape error.
Any ideas what the correct shape can be?
P.S. I found this post which involves a lot of coding, but since there is a parameter to set the color, I guess there's an easier way: How to specify colormap when saving tiff stack

See https://forum.image.sc/t/saving-tiff-stack-with-a-colormap-with-tifffile-library/101788/2

Some more examples for up to 7 different channels can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258287/how-to-specify-colormap-when-saving-tiff-stack?rq=2. Modications for 16bit may be necessary.
